# Как определить выбранный элемент типа "radio" в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Всем привет! Сейчас я пишу проектную работу и у меня появилась следующая проблема: я делаю три input'а типа "radio" и одну кнопку "Sort" я хочу, чтобы пользователь выбрал любой из этих трёх radio. После чего я хочу определить выбранный элемент в своём контроллере. Как это сделать?

### Sort products by...

```
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="sortByPrice" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Price</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="sortByDiscount" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Discount</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="sortByCategory" class="custom-control-input">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">Category</label>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся группа радиобаттонов должна иметь одинаковое имя (`name`), а значение будем считывать из `value`:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="sortType" value="sortByPrice" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Price</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="sortType" value="sortByDiscount" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Discount</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="sortType" value="sortByCategory" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">Category</label>
</div>
```

Метод:

```
public handleRadio(@RequestParam("sortType") String sortType)...
```

Соответственно, тут вместо `sortType` подставится значение радиобаттона `value`, которое выбрал пользователь.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробовал, всё получилось!